# Set spelling exception in vimrc

Tags: vim

When editing a text in markdown, I don't want to highlight bibliography entries. This can be achieved with the following command:

```
:syn match CitNoSpell '\[@[^[:space:]]\+\]' contains=@NoSpell
```

However, if I enter this command to `.vimrc`, it is ignored. I assume that is because spell file is loaded after vimrc has been read, and this definition is not kept.

How should I force vim to ignore this pattern? I prefer it to stay in .vimrc, as I synchronize the file across multiple systems, but another solution would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `~/.vimrc` is loaded first (before any files), the syntax of an opened file is set only later, and syntax scripts `:syntax clear` any existing syntax stuff, including your definition.

The right place for your customization would be the [`:help after-directory`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#after-directory); i.e. `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`, as this will be sourced after `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim`.

If you insist on configuring this within your `~/.vimrc`, you can try the following autocmd, which has to be put somewhere after `:syntax on`:

```
autocmd Syntax markdown syn match CitNoSpell ...
```

PS: For consistency, as you're tweaking the Markdown syntax, your added syntax group should also start with the syntax name, i.e. `markdownCitNoSpell`.